# Unique pages for some subset of the data (e.g. homepage.com/restaurants/search?city=new-york -> homepage.com/restaurants-in-new-york)

Tags: php, cakephp

Let's say that I have a website about restaurants in the US. A user can search for e.g. New york to find all restaurants (in the database) in New York. For this I have a controller called restaurants and a search function within that controller, so the result page would have the following url homepage.com/restaurants/search?city=new-york

The result page looks the same for all searched cities apart from the restaurants retrieved by the search function.

What I want to achieve is to have a unique page with relevant content for each city (or at least all the cities I have created unique content for). E.g. for New York I would like to have a unique page with the following url homepage.com/restaurants-in-new-york. This would also give the users the possibility to browse by city instead of searching.

Can anyone please lead me in the right direction how I can achieve this? Btw, the website is built with CakePHP.

Answer (score 0):

Use [CakePHP Routes](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html).  (They have a very good walk-through on routes, how to use...etc).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, after reading about routes I think that it only solves half of my problem, i.e. the url rewriting. I also want to create unique content for each page.

Comment: Routes allows you to pass parameters... which you can do with whatever you want.

Comment: no I didn't mean that I wanted you to create my content (it would be nice, tough!). I think that your second comment answered my question. I'm gonna play around with routes and see if I can solve it. Thanks for your help!